# Getting featured image setting as background

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm using the code below to get the posts featured image URL. I need to be able to get the `large` size image, right now it's getting the URL to the original size image.

```
<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'ttrust_post_thumb_big'), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="imagewrap"><div style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important;"></div></a>
```

Comment: replace `ttrust_post_thumb_big` with `large` and see?

Comment: No it still gets the full size image

Comment: When are you setting the background? It might be already set by the time you try to change it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in the code you are using (AFAIK):

1. **`get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'ttrust_post_thumb_big')`** only has one parameter, that is `post_id`. So, it should just be `get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)`
2. **`''`** — there's no 4th parameter for `wp_get_attachment_image_src`
3. **`array( 5600,1000 )`** defines the `$size` of the image you want to be shown. You should be using `'large'` (string) since that's what you said you need.

Okay, now try this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="imagewrap">
    <div style="background: url(<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' ); ?>) !important;"></div>
</a>
```

**Reference links:** [`get_post_thumbnail_id`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id), [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

Comment: That just outputs `background: url(Array) !important;`

Comment: @Anagio okay, try the edited code and let me know if it works.